# Getting configured product child sku on product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to do the following

> 1. whenever we choose a setting for a configurable product on the product page. I would like to get the ID of the child product on the product page itself (not through add to cart observer).
>
> For example: I navigate to a "polo shirt" and then choose its color as "red", is there any way I can retrieve the SKU of the "red shirt" on the product view page itself? as right now, even if I choose "red" and get productSKU, it gets me the SKU of the "shirt" instead of the "red shirt"

Comment: you need to customize magento default functionlity. You can implement scripting for this event using prototype or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getProductByAttributes` method of the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable` class. You'll have to implement an Ajax request to a custom controller though. Here's an example of how to get the child product:

```
public function getChildProductIdAction()
{
    // get post values
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
    $attributes = $this->getRequest()->getPost('attributes');

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $childProductId = false;

    if ($product->getTypeId() === 'configurable') {
        $childProduct = $product->getTypeInstance()->getProductByAttributes($attributes, $product);
        if ($childProduct && $childProduct->getId()) {
            $childProductId = $childProduct->getId();
        }
    }

    $data = [
        'child_product_id' => $childProductId
    ];

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $response->setBody(json_encode($data));
}
```

The 'product' and 'attributes' values can be retrieved from the add-to-cart form element.